# Apache NiFi Split JSON root array

Tags: json, regex, api, split, apache-nifi

I want to use Apache NiFi's built-in processor 'SplitJson' to split a JSON array. I've done it before and it works perfectly but now I can't seem to find the right json path expression to split my json. The JSON I get is simply from github:

https://api.github.com/events

I want to get each event in a seperate flowfile. In the description of the processor it states:

> A JsonPath expression that indicates the array element to split into JSON/scalar fragments.

So because it's the root array I want to split I try using $ or @ but this won't work. Equally `*` or `[*]` or other things that I think are wrong like `$.[*]` etc. don't work. In some cases it just doesn't split anything, other times it gives an error simply saying it can't find the array.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe all you need to do is have a JSON Path of `$.*`. This should split the array into a FlowFile per element.

To demonstrate, I created and uploaded a template here[1]. It takes in the JSON using GetHTTP, splits it using SplitJSON and ends at a LogAttribute (for testing purposes). Note that I believe GitHub requires you to use https (initial testing failed using http) so you will need to configure an SSL context with a keystore.

[1] https://gist.github.com/JPercivall/e1b5ba00a45c464fd764

Comment: This is actually still not working for me .. but it's kinda weird, when it reads the JSON it seems like something changes with it. For example text editors or my google chrome app won't format the JSON properly anymore. So I'm wondering if it just can't read the JSON or something. Very weird.

Comment: When you say "... google chrome won't format the JSON properly anymore", are you saying that when you try to open [link] (https://api.github.com/events) chrome doesn't properly format the web page or are you outputting the result of SplitText to a file and chrome won't view that properly?

Comment: The second one but apparantly it is working and I thought the json wasn't being split properly because I wasn't receiving the split flowfiles, but the error was in the following processor ... My bad! But I am using ´$´ now and this is working.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working! Be sure to watch out for the little yellow bulletins on the processors to see where the problems are occurring and best of luck using NiFi in the future.